# Is there any way to avoid the ridiculous amount of escaping needed for vimscript regexes?

Tags: vim

I have a working vimscript regular expression that looks like this:

```
^\s*\(\(module\)\|\(class\)\|\(def\)\|\(it\s\)\|\(describe\s\)\)\s
```

Here is how it would look in any other language, e.g. Python:

```
^\s*((module)|(class)|(def)|(it\s)|(describe\s))\s
```

I wrote that regular expression in something like an hour of trial and failure. How am I supposed to know what requires escaping in vim regular expressions? Apparently both parenthesis and pipes need escaping, but `^` and `*` don't.

Is there any way to avoid this escaping craziness?

Comment: I wouldn't call this "craziness"; Vim's default regexp syntax is geared towards more literal searches (like you'd expect in a text editor), so that there's usually _less_ to escape.

Comment: Don't guess. You don't need to guess these things, look them up, everything is nicely documented. `:h pattern-overview`, `:h /magic`, and so on.

Comment: @glts: The issue is knowing where to look.

Comment: I wonder what is the utility of \s after "it".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep…  You want the "very magic" escape:

```
s/^\v\s*((module)|(class)|(def)|(it\s)|(describe\s))\s/hoooo hah!!!!/g
```

`:help pattern` says the exact effects, basically everything but alphanumerics becomes magic. By the way, the branch operator's lowest priority, I don't think yours differs from

```
s/^\v\s*(module|class|def|it\s|describe\s)\s/yowee!!/g
```

but it could be that I ran out of coffee this morning.

Comment: Everything you said was 100% correct :) I assumed `module|class` would be the same as `modul[ec]lass`